# ¿Porque Javascript actua correctamente cuando se sube el mismo archivo a la segunda vez?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema muy extraño. Tengo un botón para subir una imagen. Automáticamente, se muestran dos imágenes, la primera es la que has subido, y la segunda es la primera convertida a blanco y negro en un canvas. Sin embargo, eso no ocurre. Si se sube por primera vez la foto, no funciona, pero si se recarga y se sube el mismo archivo esta segunda vez, ahí ya funciona y lo pone en blanco y negro. No encuentro que tipo de fallo puede estar sufriendo. Gracias de antemano. En este link se puede ver una demostración de lo que me está ocurriendo [Tryeditor](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GFX19NN6UTMZ)

```html
<input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" onchange="mostrar()"/>
<img id="img" height="auto" width="auto"/>

<canvas height="100px" width="100px" id="image">
</canvas>

<script>

function mostrar(){
  var archivo = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(archivo);
    reader.onloadend = function () {
     document.getElementById("img").src = reader.result;  
       var widthrent = document.getElementById("img").naturalWidth;
     var heightrent = document.getElementById("img").naturalHeight;

     document.getElementById("image").height = heightrent 
     document.getElementById("image").width = widthrent
     alert(widthrent);
     var canvas = document.getElementById('image');
     var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
     ctx.filter = "grayscale(100%)";
     
     var img = document.getElementById("img");
     ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, img.width, img.height)
     alert(img.width);
     }
    
}

</script>
```

Comment: Pues si le das ejecutar al código aquí mismo en tu pregunta y pruebas con una imagen, funciona como dices que buscas. Posiblemente tiene que ver con que el tamaño del elemento que contiene las imágenes no redimensiona correctamente la primera vez.

Comment: Hola, pero si se ejecutas este codigo en un Tryeditor o en codepen o en JSFIDDle o incluso, en un archivo HTML no funciona. Aparece un alert con 0 y 0 que es el valor de width y height, creo que proviene de ahi el error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El lío parece estar en cómo se inicializan cosas dentro de tu función. Tienes que esperar a que se cargue el resultado del reader en tu variable. Así mismo, debes esperar a que el objeto que uses para representar el resultado del reader (cuando pasas eso a un base64), reciba el resultado y lo procese.

Si yo simplifico cosas, inicializo las variables por fuera de la función (que no es necesario crearlas cada vez) y fijo el contexto del canvas por fuera, funciona desde la primera vez. Me tomo la libertad de reordenar un par de cosas para evitar redundancia en los llamados. De paso, usamos una variable image para tener todo a la mano...

PD. le dejé los console.log para que veas cómo cambian los valores a medida que avanza la ejecución.

```html
<input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" onchange="mostrar()" /><br/>
<img id="imgsrc" height="auto" width="auto" src="" /><br/>
<canvas id="resImage" height="10" width="10" />

<script>
  function mostrar() {
    const archivo = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const myImgSrc = document.getElementById("imgsrc");
    const mycanvas = document.getElementById('resImage');
    var ctx = mycanvas.getContext('2d');
    var myImageObj = new Image();

    reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
      // convert image file to base64 string
      myImgSrc.src = reader.result;
      myImageObj.src = myImgSrc.src;
      console.log("img width before load: " + myImageObj.width);

      myImageObj.addEventListener('load', e => {
        console.log("img width when loaded: " + myImageObj.width);
        let widthrent = myImageObj.width;
        let heightrent = myImageObj.height;
        console.log("image initial width: " + widthrent);

        console.log("w: " + myImageObj.width + ", h: " + myImageObj.height);

        mycanvas.height = heightrent
        mycanvas.width = widthrent

        ctx.filter = "grayscale(100%)";

        ctx.drawImage(myImageObj, 0, 0, myImageObj.width, myImageObj.height);
        
        console.log("canvas width after: " + mycanvas.width);
      });

    }, false);

    if (archivo) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(archivo);
    }

  }
</script>
```

Comment: El error era similar, al final, fue básicamente probar hasta que acerté con el error: se puede poner una función SetTimeout, realizando el siguiente proceso: Se carga la imagen >>> Se representa la imagen >>> Con SetTimeout se espera medio segundo y luego se carga la imagen resultante. Gracias de todas maneras

Comment: @Programandosiempre Y si la imagen es muy pesada, entonces te toca poner un timeout más largo a mano? Siempre es mejor depender de un listener sobre un evento que igual estamos esperando. Lo otro, onloadend sólo funciona en firefox, ve y revisa en mdn que los demás navegadores no lo soportan.

Comment: @Alfabravo NO, `onloadend` tiene soporte por todos los navegadores, incluyendo IE 10. ¿De dónde sacaste eso?

Comment: @gugadev De la documentación de MDN. Ve y mira.

Comment: Especifica, tanto `FileReader` como `HTMLImageElement` tienen la misma propiedad. El primero tiene soporte por más del 90% de navegadores, la segunda, como dices por navegadores basados en Gecko y WebRender.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que es que estás obteniendo el ancho y alto de la imagen cargada inmediatamente después de setearle el `src`:

```
document.getElementById("img").src = reader.result;  

// aquí no hay garantía que la imagen ya haya sido cargada,
// por eso algunas veces obtienes 0 como alto y ancho.
var widthrent = document.getElementById("img").naturalWidth;
var heightrent = document.getElementById("img").naturalHeight;

document.getElementById("image").height = heightrent 
document.getElementById("image").width = widthrent
```

Al hacer eso **no hay garantía que la imagen haya sido cargado**. Las propiedades como `naturalWidth` y `naturalHeight` están disponibles **una vez la imagen ha terminado de cargarse**, por esa razón, con imágenes grandes (en donde se tarda más en cargar) obtienes `0` para anchou y alto.

Lo que tienes que hacer es realizar ese proceso **una vez la imagen ha cargado**. Esto lo logras por medio de `HTMLImageElement#onload`.

**Código funcional**

```js
function mostrar() {
    const archivo = document.getElementById('file').files[0];

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(archivo);
    reader.onloadend = function() {
        const img = document.getElementById('img');
        const canvas = document.getElementById('image');
    
        img.onload = function() {
            const widthrent = this.naturalWidth;
            const heightrent = this.naturalHeight;

            canvas.height = heightrent;
            canvas.width = widthrent;
            alert(widthrent);

            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.filter = 'grayscale(100%)';

            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
            alert(img.width);
        };

        img.src = reader.result;
    };
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" onchange="mostrar()"/>
<img id="img" height="auto" width="auto"/>

<canvas height="100px" width="100px" id="image">
</canvas>
```

Comment: PD: La respuesta a _¿Por qué sí funciona la segunda vez?_, es porque probablemente la imagen se cachea y la segunda vez carga mucho más rápido.

Comment: no porque, si probabas la segunda vez con OTRA imagen, igual funcionaba, sólo que quedaba con las dimensiones de la imagen anterior

Comment: @Alfabravo De todas maneras, el código de la respuesta que dejé soluciona el inconveniente, además de ser la manera correcta de ejecución del algoritmo.